# Async/Await AJAX vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

I've been trying to get my AJAX POSTs to run sequentially. I've tried using onreadystatechange but I can't get it to work. So now I've decided to try Async / Await.

The problem is, that I don't fully understand how it works. I've read and re-read the documentation on Mozilla and I have browsed SO, but I can't seem to find a similar enough example which would help me.

So, basically what I would like to do, is:

user inputs his email and clicks submit,

**1.)** AJAX POST is made to the router with username and password which gives the user internet access.

after this is done, and we get readyState 4 and Status 200,

**2.)** another AJAX POST is made, to a web server which saves the users email to the database *(router and the server are on a different network, that's why the user needs internet connection first)*

after this is done, and we get readyState 4 and Status 200

3.) the user gets redirected.

I have tried moving `open()` and `setRequestHeader()` around but it didn't help.

Here is the complete HTML/JS code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html" />
<meta charset="utf-8" />

<title>HotSpot</title>

</head>
<body>

    <form accept-charset="utf-8" name="mail" onsubmit="return false;" method="post" id="mail">
        <h1>Hotspot</h1>
        <h2>To gain internet access, enter your email.</h2>
        <br />
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" autofocus="autofocus" />
        <br />
        <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit_ok" name="submit_ok" /> <br />
    </form>

<script type="text/javascript">

document.getElementById("submit_ok").addEventListener("click", SendAjax);

    function SendAjax() {
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        console.log(email);
        // Check if fields are empty 
        if (email=="") {
            alert("Please enter your email.");
        }
        // AJAX code to submit form
        else{
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                var DONE = 4;
                var OK = 200;

                if (xhr.readyState === DONE){
                    if (xhr.status === OK){
                        var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
                        xhr2.onreadystatechange = function () {
                            if (xhr.readyState === DONE){
                                if (xhr.status === OK){     
                                    location.href = "http://server/redirected.html";
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    xhr2.open('POST', 'http://server/insertDB.php', true);
                    xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
                    var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;
                    xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));
                }
            }
        xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
        xhr.send("popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
        }
    };

</script>   
</body>
</html>
```

I think the Async/Await code should looks something like this, but as stated before, I'm really not sure what to do.

Right of the bat, I get sendAjax is not defined.

```
(async function sendAJAX(){
    const ax1 = await Ajax1()
    const ax2 = await Ajax2()
    const ax3 = await Ajax3()
})

function Ajax1(){
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'http://router/login', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    xhr.send("popup=true&username=HSuser&password=SimpleUserPassword");
}

function Ajax2(){
    let xhr2 =  new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr2.open('POST', 'http://server/insertDB.php', true);
    xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
    var useremail = document.getElementById("email").value;
    xhr2.send("Email="+encodeURIComponent(useremail));  
}

function Ajax3(){
    location.href = "http://server/redirected.html";
}
```

Comment: you should definitely use `fetch()`

Comment: I've also checked out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch but I just get confused. Should I write xhr in a different way if I'm using fetch?